# How to get only the http class from slim framework?

Tags: php, slim

I want to use only the http routing in my php project. Is there any chance I can get only the http class from slim framework into my raw php file?

Comment: just copy the file from the Slim framework's source into your app and see if it works when you try to use it. It might have some dependencies on other parts of the framework, you'll see that either from the class's code or from errors when you try to run it, but you can either bring those across as well or re-implement them. Check the license as well before you copy parts of a solution like this wholesale.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Slim used HttpFoundation from Symfony (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) ?